# ServiceStack OAuth mail.ru registration/authorization

Tags: oauth, servicestack

I want to make a authorization mail.ru but can't find provider.

someone knows how to connect mail.ru or how to configure a different provider?

[SS wiki](http://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's now an OAuth2 [MailRuAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.OAuth2/MailRuAuthProvider.cs) included in the `ServiceStack.Authentication.OAuth2` NuGet package that's available from v4.5.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).